# Why isn't submit working on mobile browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have developed a website that queries NASA's image API. The website works fine on my desktop browser. However, when I try to search from my phone, it gets stuck freshing and then crashes. Any idea how I could solve this?

The link is: https://searchnasa.herokuapp.com/

All of my javascript is written in the file functions.js, which you can view through sources.

Comment: It works on my phone, so without more information you probably won't be able to get much help here. "It gets stuck and crashes" doesn't tell us much.

Answer (score 0):

I am receiving the following error on MacOS Safari:

> This webpage was reloaded because it was using significant memory.

There are currently two requests being made for each resulting image:

- image thumbnail (https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/PIA07081/PIA07081~thumb.jpg)
- image supplemental links (https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/PIA07081/collection.json)

```js
[
  "http://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/PIA07081/PIA07081~orig.jpg",
  "http://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/PIA07081/PIA07081~small.jpg",
  "http://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/PIA07081/PIA07081~thumb.jpg",
  "http://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/PIA07081/metadata.json"
]
```

The `collection.json` requests are not being made by the [NASA Image and Video Library](https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/PIA07081/collection.json) implementation. Therefore, I believe these requests are causing your issues. You should delay these requests until the data is needed which is after the user opens the image detail modal.

You may even be able to go further by making the assumption that the image files are always in the same format. Notice, the different image sizes are simply a `~[orig|small|thumb].jpg` suffix on the image path.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me! I have little experience with JavaScript and I'm on a time constraint (due at 12 EST). Is this an easy fix or will it take time? If it is, can you please provide more insight on how to delay the request. Thanks.

Comment: It is an easy fix. The easiest solution would be replacing the `getJSON` call on line 141 with generated links based on the existing image url path. What questions do you have?